# Put a link to "how to ask" in the close box

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just realized that when a question is closed, it does not have the [ask] link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

The current message is (for questions closed for not being focused):

> Closed. This question needs to be more [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> - Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](https://foobar).

To me, it feels like a no brainer that this link should be presented to anyone who gets their question closed. After all, the reason it got closed is because the user did not know how to ask a question. I have not thought about the wording very much, but something like this maybe?

> Closed. This question needs to be more [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> - Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](https://foobar). Please also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Another alternative:

> Closed. This question needs to be more [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> - Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](https://foobar).
> - For general information about how to ask a question, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

The main thing is that a user that fails to ask a question should be directed to instructions for how to do so. I mean, when a question is closed it's EXTREMELY common that someone posts a comment about visiting that link.

What do you say?

Comment: I would integrate it into the text a bit, like "This will help others answer the question, as described in [ask]".

Comment: Does anyone know why didn't we have it before? It looks like an obvious advantage.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin The only reason I can see is that they wanted to cut down the amount of text as much as possible.